# Meaning of 'Solution'

Tags: meaning

### Meaning of ***solution***

Which one of the following does it mean?

- An attempt to solve a problem which **may or may not be correct**
- **Correct** attempt which 100% solves the problem

Refer the following context:

> I have attached my **solution** above. Please let me know if there is some mistake in the solution provided.

In this I'm not sure if my **attempt** to solve a specific problem is correct or not but I have shared it. Can the word '**solution**' be used here?

Comment: It becomes a solution only when it is correct, or fully solved in case of liquid solution.  Attempt to solve doesn't qualify the use solution.

Comment: I was just thinking of providing the context. Please Check edit. Thanks.

Comment: @RamPillai Then is it correct when someone says 'Your Solution is incorrect' ? Doesn't it seem contradicting as according to you **solution** means something that is correct but when someone says it is incorrect it is like saying 'Your correct answer is incorrect' ?

Comment: @Kaushik, I got your point, but a question "What is the solution to the problem?" seeks the correct one; not an incorrect or partly correct one, right? Am I going parallel to your points?

Comment: Check the comment in Plyton's post. In that, is the usage of solution incorrect? Rather a student should be using 'An attempt to find the solution'. Isn't?

Comment: There is an historical problem between 'solve/dissolve/resolve'. The 'solution' of a problem might well be better expressed as the 'resolution' of a problem.

Comment: Please show your attempts to solve this question (eg linked/attributed definitions).

Comment: It means you've attached a vial of some liquid with something dissolved in it.

Answer (score 1):

I am quite confident it should be close to the second one in most scenarios. A solution is the correct answer to a problem. While an attempt to solution may or may not be correct.
Consider these words/phrases: "method to solve", "finding a solution", "attempting a problem". You might get a reference.

In a small number of cases, the word has a context based meaning.

If a student says, "This is my solution to the given question."
They are giving out their method to reach the 100% correct answer. The ultimate answer has been reached but the path taken may or may not be correct here.

When the student is not 100% confident even about the final answer they might say: "this is how I have solved the question." Or, "this is my attempt to find a solution to the question."

Comment: In most scenarios when a student uses solution he is not sure if it correct or not but he feels like it is his best attempt to find the **correct answer** to a problem. Isn't?

Comment: @Kaushik Indeed. I am not entirely sure but, this is when the perspective part comes in. From the speaker's (or writer's) POV, they themselves are correct. And because we are limited to this person's (speaker's) views, it is a solution for us. On the other hand, if the audience (reader) is not limited, as in the example of a teacher listening to a student, the answer may or may not be correct. The answer may or may not be  a solution. In such a case, I believe, the student's answer may be considered a 'proposed solution'  instead of just 'solution.'

Answer (score 1):

A solution to a problem is like an answer to a question. It is simply an element of a pair. A solution may be true or false. It may be good or bad, satisfactory or unsatisfactory.  It may be partial or even irrelevant.

There’s a famous quotation from H.L. Mencken: *there is always a well-known solution to every human problem—neat, plausible, and wrong.*

However, as this page at Quote Investigator shows, many others have embraced the concept of a false solution:  https://quoteinvestigator.com/2016/07/17/solution/

It may be possible in a domain like arithmetic for there to be  correct answers. Some things are genuinely provable in a strict formal sense, although even here this requires some acceptance of unprovable assertions. We can easily agree that 2+2=4, but the answer to “what is two?” is not so simple.

Outside of arithmetic, ordinary English is full of “problems and solutions”, like “How do solve a problem like Maria” (from *The Sound of Music*), or “The answer was an Orange”, which remains searchable as a phrase in Sellar and Yeatman’s *1066 and All That*.  Even here in our little world of EL&U, down-voting and complaints about down-voting suggest that opinions differ - and that some problems may in fact have *no solution.*

To bring this back to the original question: an “attempt” is probably the better of the two choices offered by the OP, because “attempt” itself may have be qualified, and terms like “insincere attempt” are more comprehensible than “insincere truth”.